# How can I determine the cause of CF card corruption?

Tags: filesystems, postfix, flash-memory, corruption

I installed qnx in my CF card and made it bootable and it was working well.  However, yesterday it stopped working while my system was running.  Checking the filesystem revealed that it was corrupted.  I tried to view the log files but they are corrupted and inaccessible.  How can I find out how it became corrupted and which files are corrupted with bit by bit.  How  can I view the hex file of cf card data.  The card is using an ect2 filesystem.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just that the CF card is broken? One died on me recently in a similar way...

Comment: Presumably "ect2 filesystem" is "ext2 filesystem". How long has this device been running. Is there anything in the system configuration to mitigate CF cell burnout due to excessive writes to particular sectors? Wear-leveling can be important if nothing is done to mitigate repetitive writes to the same area of a file system.

Answer (score 0):

[dd_rescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) may be used to obtain a raw dump of a failed device in a way that avoids read aborts due to failed sectors.  This will not necessarily tell you why it failed, but, monitoring if failed sectors occur, and potentially where they are in the file system could help you gather information pertinent to finding a probable cause.

If the operating system image is not configured in a way that limits repetitive writes to particular sectors of a compact flash device, an OS that chatters a lot (logging, etc) can easily access the meta data area of a file system so many times that the FLASH sectors where they are stored reach their maximum write count long before the rest of the media fails.  It can be critical to use a CF device that employs wear levelling algorithms if the OS image is not crafted to avoid high volume of writes to certain areas of the media.

`dd_rescue` would give you a raw dump of the file system.  If that's what you mean by "the hex file of cf card", then I heartily recommend it.  I have used it to recover data from hard drives that have sustained hardware failures.

If you want to try to recover the log files, [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) does wonders, but for a large partition, it is time consuming and a monumental task to pick through the output of the tool.  PhotoRec can get some file extensions (pictures, mp3's, and so on) correct, but the file names are completely lost.  It does well at recovering text files.  If the CF card failed in the meta data only, this utility would let you recover the content of the log files.

These utilities are on the [SysRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd).

Hopefully you have not written to the CF card since it failed.  Never write to a failed device if you want to recover it later.  Always mount the media read only.